# Problema con unificación por claves dentro de un array

Tags: php

Tengo dos array's $componentesd y $componentesh,los unifico mediante
$componentes =array_merge($componentesd,$componentesh);
La representación gráfica mediante Log::Info($componentes) es la siguiente:

```
[2020-05-07 07:48:31] local.INFO: array (
0 => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'nombre' => 25,
 'debe' => '101754.70',
)),
1 => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'nombre' => 18,
 'debe' => '6731.34',
)),
2 => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'nombre' => 19,
 'debe' => '1319.78',
)),
3 => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'nombre' => 19,
 'haber' => '0.00',
)),
4 => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'nombre' => 18,
 'haber' => '0.00',
)),
5 => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'nombre' => 25,
 'haber' => '586300.85',
)),
6 => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'nombre' => 90,
 'haber' => '67189.38',
)),
)
```

Como se puede observar hay valores  duplicados,como el nombre 25 que está ubicada en la posición 0=> y en la posición 5=>
mi intención es unificar claves y valores ,es decir,conseguir el siguiente array :

```
 0 => 
 stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'nombre' => 25,
 'debe' => '101754.70',
 'haber'=> '586300.85'
 )),
1 => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'nombre' => 18,
 'debe' => '6731.34',
 'haber'=> '0.00'
)),
2 => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'nombre' => 19,
 'debe' => '1319.78' ,
 'haber'=>'0.00'
)),

3 => 
stdClass::__set_state(array(
 'nombre' => 90,
 'debe'='0' 
 'haber' => '67189.38',
)),
)
```

Además cuento con el array  $datos que contiene los valores 18,19,25,90
Espero haberme explicado.
Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de un array merge lo que puedes hacer es recorrer el array `$datos` y ver si cada dato está en los arrays `$componentesd` y `$componentesh` conla función `array_search`, creando un único array que recoja todos los datos de ambos en este caso en función del nombre.

Ejemplo:

```
$datos = array(18,19,25,90);
$componentesd = array(
    array("nombre" => 18, "debe" => "120.9"),
    array("nombre" => 19, "debe" => "220.9"),
    array("nombre" => 25, "debe" => "320.9")
);
$componentesh = array(
    array("nombre" => 18, "haber" => "20.0"),
    array("nombre" => 19, "haber" => "0.0"),
    array("nombre" => 90, "haber" => "120.9")
);

$a_completo = array(); 
foreach ($datos as $dato) {
    $a_each = array();
    $a_each["nombre"] = $dato;
    $keyd = array_search($dato, array_column($componentesd, "nombre"));
    if ($keyd>0 || $keyd===0) {
     $a_each["debe"] = $componentesd[$keyd]["debe"];
    } else {
     $a_each["debe"] = 0;
    }
    $keyh = array_search($dato, array_column($componentesh, "nombre"));
    if ($keyh>0 || $keyh===0) {
     $a_each["haber"] = $componentesh[$keyh]["haber"];
    } else {
     $a_each["haber"] = 0;
    }
    array_push($a_completo,$a_each);
}

print_r($a_completo);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => 18
            [debe] => 120.9
            [haber] => 20.0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => 19
            [debe] => 220.9
            [haber] => 0.0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => 25
            [debe] => 320.9
            [haber] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [nombre] => 90
            [debe] => 0
            [haber] => 120.9
        )

)
```

Comment: Perdona la insistencia,el resultado ha sido el que esperaba. Yo partia de stdClass que he convertido en array con $comp = json_decode( json_encode( $componentes ), true ); ,ahora se trata de llevar este resultado a un pdf que espera un objeto del tipo {"id":5,"suscriptor_id":7,"diario_id":5,"subcuentad_id":16,"subcuentah_id":21,"ejercicio_id":43,"imported":"1096.25","importeh":0,"concepto":14,"extensionconcepto":"Enero2019","conceptodos":14,"extensionconceptodos":"Enero0-2019","created_at":"2020-03-16 09:38:41","updated_at":"2020-03-31 15:51:57}.¿como convierto el array en un objeto? Gracias

Comment: @EDiaz la forma más sencilla es con $objeto = (object)$array;, también puedes hacerlo on json_encode/json_decode, puedes ver un ejemplo de ambos en la respuesta a esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/155164/18182